# smartctl shows hard disk problem

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I face a problem concerning my hard disk drive.
I have a Lenovo laptop z710 and I get an error message about bad sectors.
I have re-installed several distros in case it is a bug, but the problem persists.
Now I have a fresh and clean install of Ubuntu gnome 15.04 and I get this error log from `smartctl`:

```
smartctl 6.4 2014-10-07 r4002 [x86_64-linux-3.19.0-18-generic] (local
build) Copyright (C) 2002-14, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke,
www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION 
=== Model Family:     Seagate Laptop 
SSHD Device Model:    ST1000LM014-SSHD-8GB 
Serial Number:        W3823JGX
LU WWN Device Id:    5 000c50 0782a6574 
Firmware Version: LVD3 User
Capacity:    1.000.204.886.016 bytes [1,00 TB] 
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical 
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm 
Form Factor:      2.5 inches 
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show] 
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b 
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Jun 10 14:39:27 2015 EEST SMART support is:
Available - device has SMART capability. SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION === SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED See vendor-specific Attribute list
for marginal Attributes.

General SMART Values: Offline data collection status:  (0x82)   Offline
data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled. Self-test execution status:      (   0)  The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run. Total time to complete Offline  data collection:      (  150) seconds. Offline data collection capabilities:           (0x7b) SMART
execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported. SMART capabilities:            (0x0003)  Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer. Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported. Short self-test routine  recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes. Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 200) minutes. Conveyance self-test
routine recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes. SCT capabilities:
           (0x1081) SCT Status supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10 Vendor Specific
SMART Attributes with Thresholds: 
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME           FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate        0x000f   117   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       145336392   
3 Spin_Up_Time               0x0003   098   098   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0   
4 Start_Stop_Count           0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       427   
5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct      0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0   
7 Seek_Error_Rate            0x000f   072   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       17260562   
9 Power_On_Hours             0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1741  
10 Spin_Retry_Count          0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0  
12 Power_Cycle_Count         0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       409 
184 End-to-End_Error         0x0032   035   035   099    Old_age   Always   FAILING_NOW 65 
187 Reported_Uncorrect       0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       8 
188 Command_Timeout          0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       4295032837 
189 High_Fly_Writes          0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel  0x0022   061   050   045    Old_age   Always       -       39 (Min/Max 29/39) 
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       29 
193 Load_Cycle_Count         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1723 
194 Temperature_Celsius      0x0022   039   050   000    Old_age   Always       -       39 (0 13 0 0 0) 
197 Current_Pending_Sector   0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0 
198 Offline_Uncorrectable    0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0 
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count     0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
254 Free_Fall_Sensor         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1 ATA Error Count: 55 (device log contains
only the most recent five errors)   
CR = Command Register [HEX]
FR = Features Register [HEX]
SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
ER = Error register [HEX]
ST = Status register [HEX] 
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as 
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes, SS=sec, and
sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 55 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1679 hours (69 days + 23
hours)   When the command that caused the error occurred, the device
was active or idle.

After command completion occurred, registers were:   
ER ST SC SN CL CH DH   
-- -- -- -- -- -- --   
40 51 00 1d 68 09 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0009681d = 616477

Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------   
25 00 40 00 68 09 e0 00      00:00:05.692  READ DMA EXT   
25 00 40 80 51 0a e0 00      00:00:05.691  READ DMA EXT
25 00 01 00 68 09 e0 00      00:00:05.616  READ DMA EXT
25 00 40 00 68 09 e0 00      00:00:05.592  READ DMA EXT
25 00 40 00 88 09 e0 00      00:00:05.592  READ DMA EXT

Error 54 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1679 hours (69 days + 23
hours)   When the command that caused the error occurred, the device
was active or idle.

After command completion occurred, registers were:
ER ST SC SN CL CH DH   
-- -- -- -- -- -- --   
40 51 00 1b 68 09 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0009681b = 616475

Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name   
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------   
25 00 40 00 68 09 e0 00      00:00:05.592  READ DMA EXT   
25 00 40 00 88 09 e0 00      00:00:05.592  READ DMA EXT
25 00 40 c0 81 09 e0 00      00:00:05.592  READ DMA EXT
25 00 01 00 68 09 e0 00      00:00:05.515  READ DMA EXT
25 00 40 00 68 09 e0 00      00:00:05.492  READ DMA EXT

Error 53 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1679 hours (69 days + 23
hours)   When the command that caused the error occurred, the device
was active or idle.

After command completion occurred, registers were:
ER ST SC SN CL CH DH   
-- -- -- -- -- -- --   
40 51 00 2d 68 09 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0009682d = 616493

Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name   
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------   
25 00 40 00 68 09 e0 00      00:00:05.492  READ DMA EXT   
25 00 01 02 68 09 e0 00      00:00:05.399  READ DMA EXT   
25 00 40 00 68 09 e0 00      00:00:05.375  READ DMA EXT
25 00 40 40 68 09 e0 00      00:00:05.375  READ DMA EXT
25 00 40 00 08 00 e0 00      00:00:05.374  READ DMA EXT

Error 52 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1679 hours (69 days + 23
hours)   When the command that caused the error occurred, the device
was active or idle.

After command completion occurred, registers were:   
ER ST SC SN CL CH DH   
-- -- -- -- -- -- --   
40 51 00 1b 68 09 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0009681b = 616475

Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name   
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------   
25 00 40 00 68 09 e0 00      00:00:05.375  READ DMA EXT   
25 00 40 40 68 09 e0 00      00:00:05.375  READ DMA EXT   
25 00 40 00 08 00 e0 00      00:00:05.374  READ DMA EXT   
25 00 40 00 00 00 e0 00      00:00:05.374  READ DMA EXT
25 00 80 00 63 0a e0 00      00:00:05.261  READ DMA EXT

Error 51 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 1513 hours (63 days + 1
hours)   When the command that caused the error occurred, the device
was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:   ER ST SC SN CL
CH DH   -- -- -- -- -- -- --   40 51 00 f6 03 ac 0a  Error: WP at LBA
= 0x0aac03f6 = 179045366

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:   CR FR
SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name   -- -- --
-- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------   61 00 20 ff ff ff 4f 00      00:01:12.082  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED   61 00 20 ff ff ff
4f 00      00:01:12.082  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED   61 00 20 ff ff ff 4f 00 
00:01:12.082  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED   61 00 20 ff ff ff 4f 00     
00:01:12.082  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED   61 00 20 ff ff ff 4f 00     
00:01:12.082  WRITE FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1 Num  Test_Description 
Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      1734         -
# 2  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      90%      1730         -
# 3  Conveyance offline  Completed without error       00%      1730         -
# 4  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%      1730         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1730         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1  SPAN 
MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing 
Selective self-test flags (0x0):   After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk. If
Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Should I replace the HDD or send the laptop for service?

Comment: Backup your data first, then decide.

Comment: What do you mean? I have backed up my data. Is it a hardware problem?

Comment: Yes, it's a failing hard disk. If you're familiar with replacing a disk, do so ASAP. You can either attempt to clone your existing drive to a new one, or do a new install and then recover your data from backup.

Answer (score 1):

You have a hardware problem and your disk is in imminent danger of failing. (The `FAILING_NOW` error)

1. Back-up [your system and data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) (You've just been promoted to User type 4)
2. Return your disk for a new one.  (As this is happening after 69 days, it should still be under warranty)

Whether you replace the HDD yourself or send it in for replacement is up to you...  **;-)**

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**  And next time, please format the data correctly yourself.; editing your question took more time then answering it!  **>:-)**

Comment: I always adore you for clear and concise answers..way to go :)

Comment: @Fabby, the smartctl expert =)